# Searching an Array using a console interface

Tags: java, arrays, search

I posted a few days ago asking this question and got some great answers. the only problem is the code that I am currently using will only allow for a search to be made if only one object exists in the array.
Im currently using this:

```
private static void Search(Student[]Students)
        {
           // Create a scanner for input, and get the name for search
           Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.println("Type student name for search:");
           String studentName = inputScanner.nextLine();


           // use for loop to search array.
           for(int i = 0; i < Students.length; i++){
              if(Students[i].getName().equals(studentName)){
                 // If student was found, print his details and return from this function.
                 System.out.println(Students[i]);
                 return;
              }
           }

           // If we reach this point, it means the student was never found in the for loop.
           System.out.println("Student not found.");
        }
```

Ive tried using a While loop instead of a for loop which only game me the results of the first object with the searched objects name for some reason. Im in real need of some help here so any would be really great :)

I have noticed my if statement isnt right, it doesnt account for null values in the array and falls over, how would I fix this?

Comment: how are you sure more than one object exists in the `Students` array?

Answer (score 1):

First, filter students by name and collect them to the `found` list:

```
List<Student> found = Stream.of(students)
                         .filter(s -> s.getName.equals(name))
                         .collect(toList());
```

then, print results

```
if (found.size == 0) {
     System.out.println("No students found.");
} else {
    found.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

BTW, you can achieve this just by removing `return` out of the for loop in your code - it breaks the loop after the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Your return here:

```
             System.out.println(Students[i]);
             return;
```

Means that you exit the method as soon as you have found the first match. Remove that and you will go on through and find them all.

Comment: I removed the return but it is still giving me a null pointer exception?